# Vue 2.5 dynamic drop down clicks are failing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, vuejs2, vue-component

*Vue.js 2.5 dynamic dropdown*

The following hardcoded dropdown works.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="dropdown">
  <li><a href="#" v-on:click="setDate('2018-11-11')">2018-11-11</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" v-on:click="setDate('2018-11-12')">2018-11-12</a></li>
</ul>
```

But I need the dates to be dynamic so I injected the `<li>`s into the `<ul>`.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="dropdown" v-html="dropDown"></ul>

createDates: function(){
    var dates = '';
    var date = ''
    var d = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < num_days; i++){
        date = today.getDate() - i;
        d = today.getFullYear() + '-' + today.getMonth() + '-' + date;
        dates += '<li><a href="#" v-on:click="setDate(\'' +  d + '\');">' + d + '</a></li>';
    }
    this.dropDown = dates;
}
```

Problem being the `v-on:click` does not fire when the `li` is clicked.
I suspect the *DOM* has already rendered & registered all events when the `<li>`s are being injected and are not registered as events.
I have not found any examples of dynamic dropdowns in *Vue.js*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a `computed` property called `dates` and loop through it in your template as follows :

```
 computed(){

    createdDates: function(){
     var dates = [];
     var date = ''
    var d = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < this.num_days; i++){
    date = today.getDate() - i;
    d = this.today.getFullYear() + '-' + this.today.getMonth() + '-' + date;
     dates.push(d);
      }
         return  dates;
  }
       }
```

Template :

```
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="dropdown">
         <li v-for="d in createdDates"><a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="setDate(d)">{{d}}</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**Full running example**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    today: new Date(),
    num_days: 10

  },
  methods: {
    setDate(d) {
      console.log(d)
    }
  },
  computed: {
    createdDates: function() {
      var dates = [];
      var date = ''
      var d = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < this.num_days; i++) {
        date = this.today.getDate() - i;
        d = this.today.getFullYear() + '-' + this.today.getMonth() + '-' + date;
        dates.push(d);
      }
      return dates;
    }

  }

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Vue.delete">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <ul id="dropdown">
      <li v-for="d in createdDates"><a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="setDate(d)">{{d}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```